# $\lim_{y\downarrow 0}F\left(f(y),y\right)=\lim_{y\downarrow 0}F(\lim_{\tilde y\downarrow 0}f(\tilde y),y)?$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Let $(x,y)\mapsto F(x,y)$ be a smooth function on $(0,a)\times(0,b)\subset\mathbb{R}^2_+$ where $a,b\in\mathbb{R}_+$, and $y\mapsto f(y)\in (0,a)$ another smooth function on $(0,b)$ such that $\lim_{y\downarrow 0}f(y)\in(0,a)$. Is the following true?
\begin{equation}
\lim_{y\downarrow 0}F\left(f(y),y\right)=\lim_{y\downarrow 0}F\left(\lim_{\tilde y\downarrow 0}f(\tilde y),y\right).
\end{equation}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$F(x,y) := \frac{(x-1)y}{(x-1)^2+y^2}$ is smooth for $(x,y)\in \mathbb R\times (0,\infty)$. Let's take $a:=2$, $b$ can be anything. Set $f(y):=1+y\to 1\in(0,2)$ as $y\to 0$. And $f$ is also smooth. Then
$$F(f(y),y) \equiv \frac12 \quad \forall y>0,$$
but
$$ \lim_{z\to 0+}F(f(z),y) = F(1,y) \equiv 0 \quad \forall y>0.$$